# React did not render new css style

Tags: css, reactjs

This is my code logic, When user click the box , I will set the state `active` to  `true`
and `getCssStyle()` will return `drag-and-resize-box-text clicked`
and then the background image(`T`) should disappear

```
class Box extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: false,
    }
  }

  // decide which style to be used
  getCssStyle = (type) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'text':
        if (this.state.active) {
          console.log("AAA")
          return 'drag-and-resize-box-text clicked'
        } else {
          console.log("BBB")
          return 'drag-and-resize-box-text';
        }
        // break;
      default:
      return '';
    }
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({active: true});  
  }

  render() {
    return (    
          <div className={this.getCssStyle(boxType)} >
            {this.boxFillContent()}
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The dev tools show the background image is delete, but the page is still show the image
What's wrong with this??

[image]

**css**

```
.drag-and-resize-box-text{
  border: dashed 3px LightSeaGreen;
  background: url(../images/bottom/text_normal.png)  no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

.drag-and-resize-box-text.clicked{
  border: dashed 3px LightSeaGreen;
  /*background: url(../images/bottom/text_normal.png)  no-repeat;*/
  background-position:center;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.drag-and-resize-box-text.clicked should have background: none.

Also your code could be made much simpler by using

```
<div className={this.state.active ? 'drag-and-resize-box-text clicked' : 'drag-and-resize-box-text'} >
    {this.boxFillContent()}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! `background: none` works well and your code is much better!